# React Native Movies Example SearchBar

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have doubt that why in SearchScreen.js has this code line:

```
var SearchBar = require('SearchBar');
```

But I don't see any file SearchBar.js, only see SearchBar.android.js and SearchBar.ios.js. I don't understand why it can run ?

Comment: I understood now, react native have something called @providesModule, if you write "@providesModule X" in the first doc block this enables require('X'). The other method is Node's resolution.

Answer (score 2):

You'll find the answer in the React Native documentation:

[Platform Specific Code](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/platform-specific-code.html#content)

> Platform specific extensions 
>   React Native will detect when a file has a .ios. or .android. extension and load the right file for each platform when requiring them from other components.
>
> For example, you can have these files in your project:
>
> > BigButton.ios.js
> >
> > BigButton.android.js
>
> With this setup, you can just require the files from a different component without paying attention to the platform in which the app will run.
>
> > var BigButton = require('./components/BigButton');
>
> React Native will import the correct component for the running platform.

Answer (score 0):

try this 
you must use absolute path

```
var SearchBar = require('./searchBar');
```

Comment: This is a relative path, absolute paths start with a `/`, also this does not answer the question.